# get-childitem into array and other problems

Tags: powershell

I want to add every output from following code into *an array*:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\mime\Desktop\2_Import"| Where-Object {($_.lastwritetime -gt $date)} | select basename | ft -HideTableHeaders
```

Output:

```
-empty row-
10830
11042
-empty row-
-empty row-
```

1. Why does it output 3 empty rows?
2. I've tried out a few things and searched for a solution to get the numbers in an array, but nothing has worked. What can I do to address this?

Comment: What is the output from just this? `Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\mime\Desktop\2_Import"| Where-Object {($_.lastwritetime -gt $date)}`. When you say output are you putting this into a variable and querying that? Do the answers below not already help?

Comment: @Matt Code from mjolinor helped, now it works correctly with the output (no empty rows) and i can simply address the numbers in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over-complicating it with the `Format-Table`.  Try it this way:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\mime\Desktop\2_Import"| Where-Object {($_.lastwritetime -gt $date)} | select -expandproperty basename
```

Comment: Yes, this answer is correct... but it is better to show how to fish rather than hand you a fish (paraphrasing the well-known [proverb](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2015/08/28/fish/)). The key point here is that `Format-Table` should always be considered an _endpoint_, because it adds formatting codes to the output appropriate _only_ for the console to display it. Thus, you should _never_ pipe Format-Table or save it in a variable. (Same thing goes for Format-List, of course.)

Comment: @Michael Sorens - Not necessarily. I frequently pipe Format-Table to Out-String, and then save that result into a variable (which may or may not contain other text), and use that in the body of an email. Same for Format-List.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Probably because its a hidden file / folder. You can get rid of it if you add another `Where`condition:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\mime\Desktop\2_Import" | 
    Where BaseName | 
    Where-Object {($_.lastwritetime -gt $date)} | 
    select basename | 
    ft -HideTableHeaders
```

2.) Just assign the output to a variable:

```
$myResultArray = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\mime\Desktop\2_Import" | 
    Where BaseName | 
    Where-Object {($_.lastwritetime -gt $date)} | 
    select basename | 
    ft -HideTableHeaders
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer.

1.) Same output as before

2.) Does not working... exmaple outputs:

$myResultArray[2] = Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData